# How to set the location that 'minikube start' will use?

Tags: hard-drive, kubernetes, minikube

My **"C:"** disk (hard drive) is full, so I want **"D:"**'s disk space to store the data, changing where Minikube stores its files, includes configuration files, cluster state, and other related data.

How can I change the location where Minikube stores its files?

Also, I want to know if there is any other configuration about data location in minikube that I should know, so I can change it and set the other hard drive to store it.